# Nested transactions in postgresql 8.2?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

I'm working on scripts that apply database schema updates. I've setup all my SQL update scripts using start transaction/commit. I pass these scripts to psql on the command line.

I now need to apply multiple scripts at the same time, and in one transaction. So far the only solution I've come up with is to remove the start transaction/commit from the original set of scripts, then jam them together inside a new start transaction/commit block. I'm writing perl scripts to do this on the fly.

Effectively I want nested transactions, which I can't figure out how to do in postgresql.

Is there any way to do or simulate nested transactions for this purpose? I have things setup to automatically bail out on any error, so I don't need to continue in the top level transaction if any of the lower ones fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you have the possibility to use nested transactions inside postgresql using SavePoints.

Take this code example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a integer PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE FUNCTION test_exception() RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   INSERT INTO t1 (a) VALUES (1);
   INSERT INTO t1 (a) VALUES (2);
   INSERT INTO t1 (a) VALUES (1);
   INSERT INTO t1 (a) VALUES (3);
   RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN integrity_constraint_violation THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Rollback to savepoint';
      RETURN FALSE;
END;$$;

BEGIN;

SELECT test_exception();
NOTICE:  Rollback to savepoint
 test_exception 
----------------
 f
(1 row)

COMMIT;

SELECT count(*) FROM t1;
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

Maybe this will help you out a little bit.

Comment: To use savepoints in this case, I'd have to modify my existing scripts and how they are run. In this particular case, if was going to do that, I'd just remove the start/end transaction block from all my scripts and add it on seperately, making it easy to do several at once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up 'solving' my problem out of band - I use a perl script to re-work the input scripts to eliminate their start transaction/commit calls, then push them all into one file, which gets it's own start transaction/commit.