# Nested transactions in clojure.java.jdbc

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

We have a table `m1` with millions of records. We would like to produce a table `m2` with calculations on every record in `m1`. 
We're currently running it as follows:

```
(jdbc/with-db-transaction [tx connection]
  (jdbc/query tx
    [(jdbc/prepare-statement (:connection tx)
                              "select * from m1"
                              {:fetch-size 1000})]
     {:result-set-fn (process! [tx result-set] ...)}))
```

where `process!` is

```
(defn process! [tx result-set]
  (jdbc/with-db-transaction [tx tx]
    (jdbc/insert-multi! tx :m2 [:m2_column]
      (mapv (fn [r] [(calculate r)]) 
        result-set))))
```

The `select` query is using cursors and is consumed lazily. See: [clojure.java.jdbc lazy query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765943/clojure-java-jdbc-lazy-query/39782071#39782071). That's the reason it is wrapped inside the outer transaction.

Questions:

- Is a (nested) transaction with millions of records problematic for Postgres? The [clojure.java.jdbc docs](http://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/) say nested transactions are absorbed by the outer one, so effectively we only have one transaction. Is this correct?
- If we wanted to have separate transactions for the inserts, is the solution to use a different connection to the database? We already use connection pooling, so this might already be the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> nested transactions are absorbed by the outer one

This is totally true. You may check out the [sources](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc/blob/0ea6110529b04337dc4bc8e6c23bc9f566027e45/src/main/clojure/clojure/java/jdbc.clj#L672-L679): here's branch that is executed when we are already in transaction; as you can see, `func` (function that represents body of `with-transaction` macro) is just called with no additional setup.

> is the solution to use a different connection to the database?

With `clojure.java.jdbc` this seems to be the only option. Just pass your pool instead of `tx` to `process!` function. The issue is that those transactions are not nested anymore, so if inner transaction commits and outer fails due to some reason, the inner transaction won't rollback. You may achieve "nested transactions behaviour" with [raw JDBC and savepoints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786844/1336234).